# Problem with setting tableName dynamically with Spring Boot and DynamoDB using older version of spring-data-dynamodb

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on some legacy project, which uses `1.5.15.RELEASE` Spring Boot version. Due to this I am using `spring-data-dynamodb` version `4.5.7`. My problem is kind of sibling to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262542/how-to-set-tablename-dynamically-using-environment-variable-in-spring-boot).

I tried the solutions provided in that topic - including setting `TableNameOverride` and also custom `TableNameResolver`. Unfortunately all the `findBy` methods handled automatically by `spring-data-dynamodb:4.5.7` are querying static table name - let's call it `Item`.

I also have some custom methods implemented in `RepositoryImpl` class, where I `@Autowire` bean of `DynamoDBMapper`. Suprisingly, queries implemented manually (not handled by `spring-data-dynamodb:4.5.7`) are querying table with correct prefix i.e. `TEST_Item`.

ItemsRepository (this methods do not apply prefix, when querying - does not work, still queries Item table):

```java
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, ItemId>, ItemCustomRepository {
    Iterable<Item> findAllByInstanceId(Long instanceId);
    Iterable<Item> findAllByInstanceIdOrderByInsertedDateDesc(Long instanceId);
}
```

ItemsRepositoryImpl (this method do apply prefix, when querying - works fine, queries TEST_Item):

```java
public class ItemRepositoryImpl implements ItemCustomRepository {
    @Autowired
    private DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper;
    @Override
    public List<Item> findByInstanceIdAndMessageLike(Long instanceId, String search, String stepCode) {
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<Item> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Item>()
                //... here building some query - not important;

        PaginatedQueryList<Item> queryList = dynamoDBMapper.query(Item.class, queryExpression);

        return response;
    }
```

Configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(amazonDynamoDBRef = "amazonDynamoDB", dynamoDBMapperConfigRef = "dynamoDBMapperConfig", basePackages = "com.shem.datasource.nosql.repository")
public class DynamoDBConfig {

    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.region}")
    private String amazonDynamoDBRegion;
    @Value("${dynamo.proxy.host:}")
    private String proxyHost;
    @Value("${dynamo.proxy.port:80}")
    private Integer proxyPort;
    @Value("${dynamo.proxy.enabled:false}")
    private Boolean proxyEnabled;
    @Value("${amazon.dynamodb.tableNamePrefix:}")
    private String tableNamePrefix;

    @Bean
    public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();

        if (proxyEnabled) {
            clientConfig.setProxyHost(proxyHost);
            clientConfig.setProxyPort(proxyPort);
            clientConfig.setProxyProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
        }

        AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig)
                .withRegion(amazonDynamoDBRegion)
                .build();

        return amazonDynamoDB;
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDB dynamoDB(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB) {
        return new DynamoDB(amazonDynamoDB);
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig() {
        DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder builder = new DynamoDBMapperConfig.Builder();
        String finalPrefix = StringUtils.isNotBlank(tableNamePrefix) ? tableNamePrefix + "_" : "";
        
        builder.setPaginationLoadingStrategy(PaginationLoadingStrategy.ITERATION_ONLY);
        builder.setTableNameOverride(DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNamePrefix(finalPrefix));
        System.out.println("Prefix set to " + finalPrefix);
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper(AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB, DynamoDBMapperConfig dynamoDBMapperConfig) {
        return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB, dynamoDBMapperConfig);
    }
}
```

Seems like the problem is somewhere in `spring-data-dynamodb:4.5.7`, but maybe someone already faced such issue and can help. Any thoughts how to overcome this issue?

The only solutions coming to my mind are from category `not the best ideas`:

- remove `spring-data-dynamodb` at all and implement everything with just AWS Java SDK
- try to change SpringBoot version to >2 and then try using newer version of `spring-data-dynamodb`, but project glows red when trying - timeconsuming..